# Windows security software wanted, mix of personal firewall and packet filter

Tags: firewall

Many years ago, I had a Windows based security software of which I do not remember the name. It was advertised as a personal firewall, but it could do much more. After initial installation it would prompt whenever there was any packet outgoing or incoming.

On outgoing packets, you could see which applications sent the packet, could allow this packet only or create rules, which would allow all packets outgoing, incoming or both, with an optional port range and protocol for both source and destination.

On incoming packets, it showed which application was listening on the port adressed (if any), and you could either deny, allow or create a rule based on (usually) the target application, with the options listed above.

The software had an administrative interface where I could see all the rules I created, change, update or delete them, the works.

But, software gets older, and I don't have the software anymore, and it would probably be bit rot by now. the products offered as personal firewalls these days are all easy-to-use consumer products, usually not supplying this level of detail.

So, is there any W7 compatible software capable of doing this today, free or commercial? To sum up, I want to be able to see the adressed (on incoming) or sending (on outgoing) application/service/subsystem, the ports used, the protocol used, basically control all my traffic, so that there is none if I haven't created a rule for it.

Comment: You describe literally every single security software that advertises itself as a firewall.